# "Go back home" or "Home" as CTA label in 404 page?

Tags: labels, wording, cta, 404, ux-writing

I'm working on a 404-page design, and after the title and description there is a CTA button 
not sure to use which one?

is it better to use "Go back home" or just "Home" as button label for CTA

Comment: Just "Home" will fit both cases of users going back and users who didn't come from the site itself

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what your site does, you could provide helpful links on the page (maybe see what the most visited pages are). If it is a complex website, try including a search box like Mailchimp does. Check out this link. Hope it is helpful.

https://uxplanet.org/6-best-practices-for-404-pages-with-killer-ux-d9305db19ad9

Answer (score 3):

While many brands have started to use 404 pages as places to showcase their personality and/or inject a bit of humor, a 404 is still an error. The primary purpose of an error message is to help the user recover. It's best not to think of it as a landing page that requires a singular, specific CTA.

As you probably know, a 404 is caused by either a malformed link or content that has been moved or deleted. If that malformed link was on your own site or social channel, users may feel they want to notify you about that fact. Meaning you might want to encourage a "Contact" action (as StackExchange does on their 404 page).

The user wanted *something* when they followed the link that generated the 404, and it probably wasn't your homepage. You might encourage them to search, or choose from popular landing pages, or provide direct links to some of your known top tasks (e.g. signing in, resetting password, contacting support ... whatever your data shows and makes sense for your site).

Finally, Home might be a redundant link. If the 404 message exists within your standard page template, the main navigation likely already includes one or more links to your homepage.

Answer (score 2):

`Go back home` implies that you're coming from there :) which you're not.

I would just use `Go Back` and send the user to previous page.

If they click on the logo they will be sent to Homepage anyway.

Comment: If people come on that page from a different website (google search results for example) do you still want to send them back?

Comment: Agree, that's why 404 error pages are useless and should redirect the users to the homepage with 3-5 seconds timer (in my opinion). But this is another topic :) 
https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=404